# Django test always returning 301

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, redirect, status

I know there are few same posts with this problem, but they doesn't helped for me. I'm always got a 301 status in tests:

```
self.client.get('/')
```

and this:

```
self.client.get('/admin/')
```

return:

```
AssertionError: 301 != 200
```

All urls will returning 301 status... Only way that help is: `self.client.get('/', follow=True)`

Anybody knows where is problem?

Comment: Worth noting for future that this was the issue in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472094/django-secure-ssl-redirect-and-301-http-responses#42350975

Answer (score 18, accepted):

301 is status for redirection, whitch means your get request first have response that is the 301.
Http headers contains the url to redirect to...

If you want your request to follow, you have pass in follow=True, which indicates the method to automatically trigger another request to the redirect url.
There can be many redirections.

It's a common error in assertion tests.

Comment: that is `self.client.get('/', {}, True)`, not everyone wants to google this

Answer (score 5):

Open your browser to see if the tailing backslash has caused this issue.

Comment: To avoid issues with the backslash, I used `django.urls.reverse` with the named-URL instead

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error as you described.

My django code is:

```py
>>> response = self.client.get('**/admin**')
>>> self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 301 != 200
```

This is my solution:

**Option 1**

```
self.client.get('**/admin/**')
```

**Option 2**

```
self.client.get('**/admin**', follow=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the root URL protected by login? That's certainly the case for the admin URL, so it will redirect to the login page unless you have already logged in. If you have protected the root view with `@login_required` that would explain what you see.

Comment: no, any url not protected by login, except admin urls of course

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
    def test_index_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/backstage')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/backstage/', status_code=301, target_status_code=200)
```