# Django SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT and 301 HTTP responses

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, travis-ci

In environments different from local, I set `DJ_SSL_REDIRECT = True` for my Django project.

But now, all my unit tests related to REST API endpoints failed when they are run in another environment (for example, in Travis CI).

What is happening is that all HTTP responses are `301` (I'm expecting `2XX` or `4XX` in my tests) because of the `DJ_SSL_REDIRECT` setting, as explained in doc :

> If you set the SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting to True, SecurityMiddleware will permanently (HTTP 301) redirect all HTTP connections to HTTPS.

How can I deal with this in a simple way, keeping my unit tests relevant? Thanks.

Note : I'm using Django Rest Framework 3.5

Comment: Did you ever get a response here? I'm running into the same issue. My Unit tests on our staging build fail with 301 redirect.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar problem and solved it using the "secure"-attribute for the testing client post ang get functions, like

```
    response = self.client.post('/accounts/signup/', self.getvalues(), follow=True, secure=True)
```

Hope this helps!

Mikko